# Clicking in elements contained within AlphaImageLoader background on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a really really weird issue...

I have a header with some background which has the `background-size` as `cover`. For IE8 I do have this filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myawesomefile.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Which loads fine and it's shown well. However, everything inside the header, becomes un-clickable. `hover` doesn't work and they don't fire any events...

I've prepared some [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OgItUVO/8/edit) to show this behaviour.

Comment: Off topic, one thing I noticed in your jsbin code: since you're using Modernizr, you could just specify the modernizr class `.no-backgroundsize` for your IE-specific selector, rather than the `.ie-lt9` selector. That would mean you don't need all those ugly conditional comments.

Comment: Yes I know, but those are still needed for some other IE adjustments

Comment: fair enough; I understand it's just a small sample of your code. But that said, if you're using modernizr, the chances are that this would apply to most cases where you're doing IE-specific code. Kinda the whole point of using modernizr is to remove the need to do browser-specific checks.

Answer (score 0):

On of the problems with the old IE `filter` styles is that they do have some nasty glitches, which can result in weird things like this.

This specific issue is a new one on me, but it's just the kind of thing that I'm used to seeing with `filter`.

I've just spent a bit of time fiddling with your code to see if I could work around it, and I haven't got anywhere. So my suggestion would be to give up on the `filter`.

Fortunately, there is an alternative: Version 2 of the [CSS3Pie library](http://css3pie.com/) includes a polyfill for `background-size`, which means that it can be supported in all IE versions.

There are some caveats with CSS3Pie as well; obviously it's a Javascript library, so will fail if your users don't have JS enabled. And it requires you to use the shorthand `background` syntax rather than a separate `background-size` property. But the point is that it *does* work, whereas clearly your current solution doesn't, so I'd say it's worth a try.

Hope that helps.